# sleeping connection (mysql) mcrypt

Tags: php, mysql, centos, database-connection, mcrypt

I have isolated some code within some other guys code which is causing our servers to grind to a halt. This occurs every time an mcrypt function is called.

```
$iv = ($iv === false) ? mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($this->td), $random_seed) : substr($iv, 0, mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($this->td));
```

$iv by default is false. As such every time mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($this->td), $random_seed) is called. We see a build up of sleeping connection states.

Has anyone got any idea as to why. I've done a little probing and can't seem to figure out a solution to this particular line.

Comment: Only ideas I have is using `MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM` instead (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-create-iv.php) and checking permissions on /dev/random and /dev/urandom.

Comment: Boom, you sir are a superstar. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM instead (see 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-create-iv.php
) and check permissions on /dev/random and /dev/urandom.

See Wikipedia for when dev urandom is better and when dev random:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random